# Can I create a custom Message Bar in Microsoft Access?

Tags: forms, ms-access, ribbon

I know that I can customize the Ribbon in Microsoft Access (and other Office programs), but is it possible to create a some sort of custom *Message Bar?*

Example Message Bars from [Office.com](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/enable-or-disable-security-alerts-on-the-message-bar-adbf15d9-9195-4498-bdc3-5cb0dfe93852):

[image]
[image]

My objective is to create something, like a form, that can be displayed *between* the standard Ribbon and the object tabs, and be made visible/invisible, as developer desires.

Possible?